# When I compiled my files, why could I not compile the style files?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, less

English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

I generated a workspace [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9B6Y.png);

Then I run "tsc -p ." to compile my files;

Here is the generated files [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NXLb.png)

I can't find "index.less" in the dist directory.

This means that when run "tsc", style files is not compiled.
So how could I compile style file by tsc or other ways;

thanks;

Comment: I appreciate your effort but we need someone to edit this question I'm not clear what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

`tsc` stands for `typescript compiler`. It compiles typescript to javascript.

If you want to compile scss you need an scss compiler, for example `node-sass` You can install it using `npm install node-sass`

VS Code also has a scss extension to compile styles, you can find it in the extension marketplace.